# Strimzi Kafka on Kubernetes local bare metal

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, strimzi

I have a kubernetes cluster running on multiple local (bare metal/physcal) machines.
I want to deploy kafka on the cluster, but I can't figure out how to use strimzi with my configuration.

I tried to follow the tutorial on the quickstart page : https://strimzi.io/docs/quickstart/master/
Got my zookeeper pods pending at point `2.4. Creating a cluster` :

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
  ----     ------            ----       ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
```

I usually use `hostpath` for my volumes, I don't know what's going on with this...

**EDIT**: I tried to create a StorageClass using Arghya Sadhu's commands, but the problem still there.
The description of my PVC :

```
kubectl describe -n my-kafka-project persistentvolumeclaim/data-my-cluster-zookeeper-0
Name:          data-my-cluster-zookeeper-0
Namespace:     my-kafka-project
StorageClass:  local-storage
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-cluster
               app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=strimzi-cluster-operator
               app.kubernetes.io/name=strimzi
               strimzi.io/cluster=my-cluster
               strimzi.io/kind=Kafka
               strimzi.io/name=my-cluster-zookeeper
Annotations:   strimzi.io/delete-claim: false
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    my-cluster-zookeeper-0
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                 From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----                ----                         -------
  Normal  WaitForFirstConsumer  72s (x66 over 16m)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
```

And my pod:

```
kubectl describe -n my-kafka-project pod/my-cluster-zookeeper-0
Name:           my-cluster-zookeeper-0
Namespace:      my-kafka-project
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-cluster
                app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=strimzi-cluster-operator
                app.kubernetes.io/name=strimzi
                controller-revision-hash=my-cluster-zookeeper-7f698cf9b5
                statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=my-cluster-zookeeper-0
                strimzi.io/cluster=my-cluster
                strimzi.io/kind=Kafka
                strimzi.io/name=my-cluster-zookeeper
Annotations:    strimzi.io/cluster-ca-cert-generation: 0
                strimzi.io/generation: 0
Status:         Pending
IP:             
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/my-cluster-zookeeper
Containers:
  zookeeper:
    Image:      strimzi/kafka:0.15.0-kafka-2.3.1
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      /opt/kafka/zookeeper_run.sh
    Liveness:   exec [/opt/kafka/zookeeper_healthcheck.sh] delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  exec [/opt/kafka/zookeeper_healthcheck.sh] delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_NODE_COUNT:          1
      ZOOKEEPER_METRICS_ENABLED:     false
      STRIMZI_KAFKA_GC_LOG_ENABLED:  false
      KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS:               -Xms128M
      ZOOKEEPER_CONFIGURATION:       autopurge.purgeInterval=1
                                     tickTime=2000
                                     initLimit=5
                                     syncLimit=2

    Mounts:
      /opt/kafka/custom-config/ from zookeeper-metrics-and-logging (rw)
      /var/lib/zookeeper from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from my-cluster-zookeeper-token-hgk2b (ro)
  tls-sidecar:
    Image:       strimzi/kafka:0.15.0-kafka-2.3.1
    Ports:       2888/TCP, 3888/TCP, 2181/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Command:
      /opt/stunnel/zookeeper_stunnel_run.sh
    Liveness:   exec [/opt/stunnel/stunnel_healthcheck.sh 2181] delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  exec [/opt/stunnel/stunnel_healthcheck.sh 2181] delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_NODE_COUNT:   1
      TLS_SIDECAR_LOG_LEVEL:  notice
    Mounts:
      /etc/tls-sidecar/cluster-ca-certs/ from cluster-ca-certs (rw)
      /etc/tls-sidecar/zookeeper-nodes/ from zookeeper-nodes (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from my-cluster-zookeeper-token-hgk2b (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data-my-cluster-zookeeper-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  zookeeper-metrics-and-logging:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      my-cluster-zookeeper-config
    Optional:  false
  zookeeper-nodes:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes
    Optional:    false
  cluster-ca-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  my-cluster-cluster-ca-cert
    Optional:    false
  my-cluster-zookeeper-token-hgk2b:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  my-cluster-zookeeper-token-hgk2b
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
  ----     ------            ----       ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind.
```

Comment: output of kubectl describe pvc ?

Comment: What version of Kubernetes and kubeadm are you using? Also Please provide describe of your `PV` and `PVC`.

Comment: I missed a PV, I created one and the problem was fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a [PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume) fulfilling the constraints of the PersistentVolumeClaim.

Use local storage. Using a [local](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local) storage class:

```
$ cat <<EOF
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
EOF | kubectl apply -f -
```

You need to configure a default storageClass in your cluster so that the PersistentVolumeClaim can take the storage from there.

```
$ kubectl patch storageclass local-storage -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"}}}'
```

Comment: Can't we use `hostpath` on strimzi instead of creating PersistentVolume or StorageClass ? I tried your commands to create and patch, but it still pending

Comment: what do you mean by "hostpath instead of PV"? hostpath is a type of PV: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes

Comment: I always used `hostpath` which no need additional claim. We just have to use this simple pattern in a deployment for example :  `volumes: { name: "name", hostPath: {path} }`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when running on bare metal and I tried the storage class method mentioned by @arghya-sadhu but it still didn't work. I found out that the storage class which strimzi is using is a specific type for local storage as mentioned [here](https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/07/08/persistent-storage-improvements/). Also, for each replica you will need a different storage class and a persistent volume that has a different directory.

For example, the snippet below will create 3 replicas for Zookeeper and Kafka.

 You need to replace "node2" with the name of the node that you are assigning the data to. You can find the nodes in your cluster with

```
kubectl get nodes
```

Then you need to create the directories for each storage class because they can't be in the same directory otherwise you'll get an error

```
ssh root@node2
mkdir /mnt/pv0 /mnt/pv1 /mnt/pv2
```

After that, you can run this snippet to create storage classes and persistent volumes.

 "storage-class-and-pv.yaml"

```yaml
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: class-0
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  encrypted: "true"
  fsType: "xfs"
reclaimPolicy: Delete
allowVolumeExpansion: true
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: class-1
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  encrypted: "true"
  fsType: "xfs"
reclaimPolicy: Delete
allowVolumeExpansion: true
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: class-2
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  encrypted: "true"
  fsType: "xfs"
reclaimPolicy: Delete
allowVolumeExpansion: true
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-0
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: class-0
  local:
    path: /mnt/pv0
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: class-0
  local:
    path: /mnt/pv0
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-2
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: class-1
  local:
    path: /mnt/pv1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-3
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: class-1
  local:
    path: /mnt/pv1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-4
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: class-2
  local:
    path: /mnt/pv2
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-5
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: class-2
  local:
    path: /mnt/pv2
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node2
```

Once you create that, you can deploy your Kafka and Zookeeper cluster. Just make sure to override the classes for storage.

 "sample-kafka-cluster.yaml"

```yaml
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-sample-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.2.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 1
      default.replication.factor: 1
      min.insync.replicas: 1
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.2"
    storage:
      type: jbod
      volumes:
      - id: 0
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 1Gi
        deleteClaim: true
        overrides:
        - broker: 0
          class: class-0
        - broker: 1
          class: class-1
        - broker: 2
          class: class-2
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 3
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 1Gi
      deleteClaim: true
      overrides:
        - broker: 0
          class: class-0
        - broker: 1
          class: class-1
        - broker: 2
          class: class-2
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it sounds to me that there is something missing on Kubernetes at infrastructure level. You should provide PersistentVolumes which are used for static assign to PVCs or as already mentioned by Arghya you can provide StorageClasses for dynamic assignment.

Comment: I tried using StorageClass it does nothing new. And I want to avoid the redundancy of PV - PVC

Comment: Can you provide me the list of "installed" storage classes available in your cluster, the PVs and finally the `Kafka` custom resource you are using for deploying the cluster please?

Comment: I have no storage classes installed, or the default only I Assume. It's a new cluster I created to test strimzi. The only things on the cluster are detailled in the link I provided (the quickstart for strimzi)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was creating kafka in another namespace `my-cluster-kafka` but the strimzi operator was on namespace `kafka`.

So I just created in the same namespace. For test purporse I use a ephemeral storage.

Here the kafla.yaml:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    replicas: 1
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: tls
      - name: external
        port: 9094
        type: nodeport
        tls: false
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 1
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 1
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```